# Wierd bug that render wrong some parts in the screen

Tags: windows-10, drivers, video, display, dell-studio

I am using an old notebook (Dell Studio 17) that is having a strange screen bug, as seen in the following images

[image: img-1]
[image: img-2]
[image: img-3]

The strange thing is that it only appears in Windows, within everything relevant to BIOS it works correctly!

¿What did i try?

- Reinstall drivers
- Reinstall Windows 10 again

But i'm out of ideas, what can i do?

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: What graphics card does it have? I've seen that happen on older Intels with no current drivers for Win10.

Comment: @Tetsujin Hey, thanks for your time, the only i know, is that it is a Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family (dxdiag info) do you know if any common drivers exists to make it work well on Windows 10? or what do you recommend?

Comment: There have never been any drivers for that chipset in Win10. See what you can find directly at Intel - https://downloadcenter.intel.com - they did do one last update for some cusp chipsets, idk if that one is new enough though, it's far too old. Frankly, MS shouldn't have offered you the Win10 update on that machine in the first place.

Comment: Thanks you for your time, i will try! Answer the question if you want, so i can mark it as correct!

Comment: See if you can find a driver that helps, then we can get a 'working' answer rather than open-ended one :)

Comment: What happens if you boot it to another operation system, e.g. a Linux distro on a thumbdrive? If it displays the same in high res then it may also be that the connector to the LCD screen is bad (it passes to the screen through the hinge, a moving part). That used to happen a lot in days past, and the screen looks a bit too much like a bad cable connection to my liking.

Comment: As @MaartenBodewes suggests, you can run Linux from a USB drive without having to install it, e.g. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows . But if it runs well and meets your needs, you might choose to install it instead of Windows 10, or alongside (dual boot).